# 'cap production setup' & 'cap production deploy' doesn't execute

Tags: deployment, capistrano

I've set up all of things for deploy ruby on rails by capistrano on ubuntu server 14.10
but when i execute command by cap production setup or deploy
i've got this error message so i found out path by .rbenv/bin/rbenv but there wasn't

how can i solve this problem
following is what i got error message
thank you

```
**DEBUG [2814493d] Finished in 3.501 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [3f8ba0c4] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build ] as 

deployer@railserver.cloudapp.net

DEBUG [3f8ba0c4] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build ]

DEBUG [3f8ba0c4] Finished in 0.012 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [243e2a34] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 ] as 
deployer@railserver.cloudapp.net

DEBUG [243e2a34] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2 ]

DEBUG [243e2a34] Finished in 0.009 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [7a6e00da] Running RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec gem query 
--quiet --installed --name-matches ^bundler$ as deployer@railserver.cloudapp.net

DEBUG [7a6e00da] Command: ( PATH=~/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv 
RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec gem query 
--quiet --installed --name-matches ^bundler$ )

DEBUG [7a6e00da]        bash: /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/rbenv: No such file or directory

DEBUG [7a6e00da] Finished in 0.009 seconds with exit status 127 (failed).

INFO [d6c3086f] Running RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec gem install 
bundler --quiet --no-rdoc --no-ri as deployer@railserver.cloudapp.net

DEBUG [d6c3086f] Command: ( PATH=~/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv 
RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec gem install 
bundler --quiet --no-rdoc --no-ri )

DEBUG [d6c3086f]        bash: /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/rbenv: No such file or directory

(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)

cap aborted!

SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@railserver.cloudapp.net: gem 
exit status: 127

gem stdout: Nothing written

gem stderr: bash: /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/rbenv: No such file or directory

SSHKit::Command::Failed: gem exit status: 127

gem stdout: Nothing written

gem stderr: bash: /home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/rbenv: No such file or directory

Tasks: TOP => rbenv:install_bundler

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

deployer@railserver:~/rubyonrailstest$ cap aborted!

Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage 
you have defined.**
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [capistrano-rbenv-install plugin](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-rbenv-install). It makes problems like the one you have disappear.